# Finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}((t))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a number field. Is every finite extension of $K((t))$ of the form $L((\pi^{1/e}))$, where $L/K$ is finite and $\pi = a_1t + a_2t^2 + \cdots$ for some $a_i\in L$?

Is every finite flat extension of $K[[t]]$ of the form $L[[\pi^{1/e}]]$ with $\pi = a_1t + a_2t^2 + \cdots$ for some $a_i\in L$?

What's a good book for stuff like this? (most(all?) books I know which discuss local fields require that the field be locally compact, so $\mathbb{Q}_p$ or $\mathbb{F}_q((t))$).

What theorems for locally compact complete topological (local) fields fail for fields like $\mathbb{Q}((t))$?

Of course the theorem: "A locally compact complete topological local field has finite residue fields" would fail for $\mathbb{Q}((t))$, so that's not what I'm asking. I would like to understand where local compactness is used in the usual theory of local fields.

Comment: Assume that $K$ has characteristic $p$. Consider the Artin-Schreier extension $K((t))[u]$, where $u$ is a zero of 
$$m(x)=x^p-x-\frac1t\in K((t))[x].$$  In terms of $v=1/t$ we can think of $u$ as
$$u=v^{1/p}+v^{1/p^2}+v^{1/p^3}+\cdots.$$ I don't see how that would fit into the scheme in the first paragraph of your question.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't understand your objection. I assume that $K$ is a number field.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I somehow managed to miss that.